# If $b_n$ is a sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }3^{n}b_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove?

If $b_n$ is a sequence such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }3^{n}b_n$ converges, then
the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }2^{n}b_n$ converges absolutely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

We have $2^nb_n=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n \cdot  (3^nb_n)$.

By assumption, the second factor converges to zero, hence its absolute value is smaller than $1$ at some point. We deduce $|2^nb_n| \leq \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$ for $n \gg 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison test,  since $3^n >2^n \ \forall n \geq 1$:
$$
\sum_n 3^n b_n \geq \sum_n 2^n b_n
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint for the series to converge $1/b_n\geq 3^n$ so for any value less than or equal to $3$ the series converges .for example let $b_n=6^n$